# Is there any way to draw a pitch track, sound wave, and annotation in Praat?

Tags: phonetics, phonology, praat

I can draw a combination of a Sound and a TextGrid, and the combination of a Pitch and a TextGrid, but I cannot draw the combination of all three, like it appears in the editor window.

Is this a weakness in Praat, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to do that either, and I think the most convenient way to do so is to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "out-of-the-box" way of drawing the combination of a Sound, Pitch, and TextGrid object, to form something similar to what you see in the TextGrid editor. However, this does not mean that it cannot be done. You can script this command, making use of one of Praat's *strengths*.

Whatever you do, *please*, **do not put screenshots on your papers**.

Save the following script somewhere you can find it and then execute it with a Sound and TextGrid object selected. You can also select a Pitch object to draw, but if you don't select one, one will be generated with the values you've provided.

The options for the command work in exactly the same way as the equivalent options for the corresponding commands (the Sound options are the same as for the Sound's `Draw...` command, etc).

The resulting graph should have the same style as that of the rest of Praat's commands.

[image: Combination of a Sound, TextGrid and Pitch objects]

```
# Combine the draw commands for Sound,
# Pitch and TextGrid objects

form Draw annotated Sound and Pitch...
  real left_Time_range_(s)        0
  real right_Time_range_(s)       0 (= all)
  real left_Vertical_range        0
  real right_Vertical_range       0 (= auto)
  real left_Frequency_range_(Hz)  0
  real right_Frequency_range_(Hz) 500
  optionmenu Sound_drawing_method: 1
    option Curve
    option Bars
    option Poles
    option Speckles
  boolean Show_boundaries yes
  boolean Use_text_styles yes
  boolean Garnish yes
  comment What proportion of the graph should be used for the Sound?
  positive Figure_ratio 0.5
endform

# Get information on current picture
info$ = Picture info
original_colour.r$ = extractWord$(info$,  "Red:")
original_colour.g$ = extractWord$(info$,  "Green:")
original_colour.b$ = extractWord$(info$,  "Blue:")
picture.line_width = extractNumber(info$, "Line width:")
picture.left       = extractNumber(info$, "Inner viewport left:")
picture.right      = extractNumber(info$, "Inner viewport right:")
picture.top        = extractNumber(info$, "Inner viewport top:")
picture.bottom     = extractNumber(info$, "Inner viewport bottom:")
picture.height     = picture.bottom - picture.top

# Sound options
sound.start   = left_Time_range
sound.end     = right_Time_range
sound.min     = left_Vertical_range
sound.max     = right_Vertical_range
sound.method$ = sound_drawing_method$

# Pitch options
pitch.min     = left_Frequency_range
pitch.max     = right_Frequency_range
pitch.created = 0

# Draw options
fzero.colour$      = "Cyan"
fzero.width        = 2
fzero.border       = 1
fzero.border_width = 2
point.marker_size  = 0.1
precision          = 3

# Identify objects
# If no Pitch object is selected, generate one
sound = selected("Sound")
textgrid = selected("TextGrid")
if numberOfSelected("Pitch")
  pitch = selected("Pitch")
else
  selectObject: sound
  pitch = To Pitch: 0,
    ... if !pitch.min then 75  else pitch.min fi,
    ... if !pitch.max then 600 else pitch.max fi
  pitch.created = 1
endif

# Identify ranges for sound
selectObject: sound
if !sound.start and !sound.end
  sound.start = Get start time
  sound.end = Get end time
endif
sound.duration = sound.end - sound.start
if !sound.min and !sound.max
  sound.min = Get minimum: sound.start, sound.end, "None"
  sound.max = Get maximum: sound.start, sound.end, "None"
endif

# Select top of figure, for Sound and Pitch data
Select inner viewport:
  ... picture.left,
  ... picture.right,
  ... picture.top,
  ... picture.top + (picture.height * figure_ratio)

# Draw sound
selectObject: sound
Draw: sound.start, sound.end, sound.min, sound.max, "no", sound.method$

# Garnish sound
if garnish
  Draw line: sound.start, sound.min, sound.end, sound.min
  if sound.min < 0 and sound.max > 0
    One mark left: 0, "yes", "yes", "no", ""
  endif
  One mark left: sound.min, "no", "yes", "no", fixed$(sound.min, precision)
  One mark left: sound.max, "no", "yes", "no", fixed$(sound.max, precision)
endif

# Extract range from TextGrid object
selectObject: textgrid
textgrid_part = Extract part: sound.start, sound.end, "yes"
total_tiers = Get number of tiers
tier.height = 1 / total_tiers

# Draw boundaries (on Sound and Pitch)
if show_boundaries
  for tier to total_tiers
    interval_tier = Is interval tier: tier
    item$ = if interval_tier then "interval" else "point" fi
    total_items = do("Get number of " + item$ + "s...", tier)
    for item to total_items
      if interval_tier
        time = Get end point: tier, item
      else
        time = Get time of point: tier, item
      endif
      One mark bottom: time, "no", "no", "yes", ""
  endfor
endif

# Draw pitch, above boundaries
selectObject: pitch
if fzero.border
  Line width: fzero.width + fzero.border_width
  White
  Draw: sound.start, sound.end, pitch.min, pitch.max, "no"
endif
Line width: fzero.width
Colour: fzero.colour$
Draw: sound.start, sound.end, pitch.min, pitch.max, "no"
Line width: 1

# Garnish pitch
if garnish
  One mark right: pitch.min, "yes", "yes", "no", ""
  One mark right: pitch.max, "no", "yes", "no", fixed$(pitch.max, 0)
  Text right: "yes", "Pitch (Hz)"
endif

# Return to original colour
Colour: "{" +
  ... original_colour.r$ + "," +
  ... original_colour.g$ + "," +
  ... original_colour.b$ + "}"

if 1 - figure_ratio
  # Select bottom of figure, for TextGrid data
  Select inner viewport:
    ... picture.left,
    ... picture.right,
    ... picture.top + (picture.height * figure_ratio),
    ... picture.bottom

  # Adjust vertical axis
  Axes: sound.start, sound.end, 1, 0

  # Draw TextGrid
  # A custom draw method is needed to ensure that the TextGrid is
  # drawn using only the part of the figure specified by the user
  selectObject: textgrid_part
  for tier to total_tiers
    tier.bottom = tier * tier.height
    tier.top = tier.bottom - tier.height
    tier.middle = tier.top + (tier.height / 2)
    if garnish and tier < total_tiers
      Draw line: sound.start, tier.bottom, sound.end, tier.bottom
    endif

    interval_tier = Is interval tier: tier
    item$ = if interval_tier then "interval" else "point" fi
    total_items = do("Get number of " + item$ + "s...", tier)
      for item to total_items
        if interval_tier
          time = Get end point: tier, item
          start = Get starting point: tier, item
          midpoint = start + ((time - start) / 2)
          if garnish
            Draw line: time, tier.bottom, time, tier.top
          endif
        else
          time = Get time of point: tier, item
          midpoint = time
          if garnish
            Draw line: time, tier.top, time, tier.top + tier.height * point.marker_size
            Draw line: time, tier.bottom, time, tier.bottom - tier.height * point.marker_size
          endif
        endif

        label$ = do$("Get label of " + item$ + "...", tier, item)
        if !use_text_styles
          label$ = replace$(label$, "\", "\bs", 0)
          label$ = replace_regex$(label$, "([%#^_])", "\\\1 ", 0)
        endif
        Text: midpoint, "Centre", tier.middle, "Half", label$
      endfor
  endfor
endif
removeObject: textgrid_part

# Select the full viewport
Select inner viewport:
  ... picture.left,
  ... picture.right,
  ... picture.top,
  ... picture.bottom

# Finish garnish
if garnish
  Draw inner box
  One mark bottom: sound.start, "no", "yes", "no", fixed$(sound.start, precision)
  One mark bottom: sound.end,   "no", "yes", "no", fixed$(sound.end,   precision)
  Text bottom: "yes", "Time (s)"
endif

# Re-select original objects
selectObject: sound, textgrid

# Remove Pitch object if it was created by us
# or add it to selection
if pitch.created
  nocheck removeObject: pitch
else
  plusObject: pitch
endif
```

Comment: Can you explain why you say "Whatever you do, please, do not put screenshots on your papers"? I'm asking as an end-user, not a programmer: what is the concern, and what is the alternative?

Comment: @user6726 What goes into making a good scientific plot and what goes into making a good user interface are completely different things. A screenshot carries a lot of information that is not useful, and ends up just being distracting. Besides, with [extremely rare exceptions](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gtk-vector-screenshot/), screenshots are made as raster graphics, which often end up looking terrible when printed. The alternative is a nice, carefully designed, scalable vector graphic, which is more aesthetically pleasing and better at communicating what you mean.