# Drawing labels on a Praat Sound plot

Tags: praat

What commands do I need in a Praat script to draw labels for the minimum and maximum of a Sound object?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Praat only has one "script language". What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? What doesn't work, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: What is the code, i.e. terminology I need to use. I have basic skills in scripting, and I have done some online tutorials, but I cannot find the "language" or "terms" to draw a custom waveform. When I use the Praat interface to draw a waveform and check on "Garnish", it draws the sound min and max, and the duration start and end along with label Times (s).  I want to customize the garnishment so that duration start, end and label are not drawn.

Comment: I tried to adapt part of the script found here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/16877/is-there-any-way-to-draw-a-pitch-track-sound-wave-and-annotation-in-praat, but I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: Without knowing what you did or _how_ it is not working, it is hard for anyone to help. You might have to start a new question for that. For this one, though, did the commands I linked to in my answer below not help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lines 99-100 in the script I posted in this [other question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/16910/10119), which combines the plotting of `Sound`, `Pitch`, and `TextGrid` objects while reproducing the plotting scheme in the default Praat figures. I suspect the commands you want are in the [`One mark left/right/top/bottom...`](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/One_mark_left_right_top_bottom___.html) family of Picture window commands.

The sound minimum and maximum, on the other hand, are calculated from the [`Get minimum...`](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Sound__Get_minimum___.html) and [`Get maximum...`](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Sound__Get_maximum___.html) commands for `Sound` objects.